# Http request and response headers headers

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers

I want to know the difference between request and response headers based on these factors -

1. between Expires, Date, Age, and If-Modified
2. Do Not Track
3. Cache-Control
4. Transfer-Encoding
5. ETag
6. X-Frame-Options

I  have referred to these docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers but didn't find any proper details

Comment: Request headers come from the client and are sent to the server as part of the HTTP request.  Response headers come from the server and are sent as part of the response to that request.  Did you have a different question?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The details are deeper in the documentation ([example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)), please follow the links on that [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Caching) page.